# Lost connection to iPhone after moving back and forth through view controllers a number of times

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

My program is one where a number of view controllers have to be pushed and popped a number of times. After a while the app stops running and seems to crash. This crash, if it is one, was never detectable on Crashlytics as well. While debugging it works well for some time but then after a number of times it says 'Lost connection to iPhone'. This was being tested on iPhone 4s. Every time this happens the app stops at this line of code, although it works for a number of times prior to that:

```
ManifestDocumentViewController *manifestVC = (ManifestDocumentViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"manifestImage"];
```

The Base SDK is iOS 9.2 and the Deployment Target is 8.0. I have placed logs for the storyboard and for the view controller. Both exist:

```
2016-07-14 20:08:28.444 App[5445:402097] self.storyboard <UIStoryboard: 0x________>

2016-07-14 20:08:28.451 App[5445:402097] [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@manifestImage] <ManifestDocumentViewController: 0x________>
```

Can any one let me know why is this happening and what is the solution.

Comment: when the crash highlights that line, did you try to see if storyboard is nil or viewController is nil at that point ? Also please include what version of iOS you are using and other details that you believe could be the casue of the issue.

Comment: Yes I have added them now in the last edit